# Interstitial Ads not showing admob plugin for unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am trying to put an interstitial ad after every 5 games the user plays. What I've done is created an empty object with the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdBetweenGames : MonoBehaviour {
    InterstitialAd interstitial;

    void Start()
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("games-played", -1) % 5 == 0)
        {
            this.ShowInterstitial();
        }
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        string adUnitId = "UNITID";


        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }

    public void ShowInterstitial()
    {     
        RequestInterstitial();
        Debug.Log("Interstatial ad called.");
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure the code here is called properly based on the debug log. I've also tried doing banner ads and they show without a problem after 1-2 seconds. I am making an android game.

Also I was thinking, could it be that the ad needs some extra time to load and I am clicking try again too early. But then what would a solution be?

Comment: First: Do not post your ad unit id - its not safe. I alreade deleted it. Second: Did you wait? Sometimes it takes time for first ad to load

Comment: I did wait about 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Put Debug.Log inside `if (interstitial.IsLoaded())` and see if that's even true.

Comment: Tried it. It seems to be true as the code inside is being called. Also I have the "Dummy Show Interstitial" from the default logging.

Comment: Maybe you should file for a bug on admob [github page](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues). Simply click on New Issue button.

Comment: Sometimes it takes up to 1 minute for ad to load

Answer (score 0):

The interstitial ad of ad mob need time to load try it in update and wait for at least 4 sec and call `ShowInterstitial` function inside a `bool` set its value `true` in start and `false` it after calling the function to show ad once.